# replace all arabic number inside uilabel string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Nsstring like this : "2015/18/02 4:19"

is it possible to change the output of uilabel like to hindu or arabic like this ?

: " ٤:١٩ ٢٠١٥/١٨/٠٢ "

as i checked out there are three type of formatter in apple document :

NSNumberFormatter,
NSDateFormatter,
NSLocalizedString.

should i convert this string to date or number and then change the format with

this :

```
[formatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"]];
```

or create "Localizable.strings" with my number and set the text to change per my

key ? or is there better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use one of the locale identifiers that have the English numeral symbols. E.g:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEEE dd MMM | hh:mm a";
dateFormatter.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar_TN"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

This will print:

```
الخميس 14 جانفي | 02:02 م
```

For a full list of dates in the locales supported for iOS check this:

https://gist.github.com/devinfoley/5980066